# Printing from swing on Mac & Windows - Where is postscript support?

Tags: java, windows, swing, printing, postscript

I'm printing a complicated swing application UI to a physical printer via an Airport.  I've got Mac & windows machines both printing to the same printer.  Printing from the Mac looks great.  Printing from windows looks far from great - everything is very pixelated, including fonts and graph lines.

Some digging around reveals that the available PrintServices are different for the different platforms.

```
DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.POSTSCRIPT;
PrintRequestAttributeSet attrs = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, attrs);
```

When executed from the mac, the above returns a single-element array.  From windows, it returns an empty array.  This leads me to believe that windows is sending a 72 DPI image to the printer, instead of postscript data.

Is this a difference in the mac & windows JVM implementations?  Is there any workaround to get printing on Windows working?  I realize I could generate my own 350dpi rasterized image and send that to the printer, but these things go into the hundreds of pages, I really would like to avoid that route if possible.

Comment: I stumbled upon this question and I know it is ancient and you're probably aware of this, but the second line of code is unnecessary, `lookupPrintServices` allows for the second argument to be `null` in case you don't need to set attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think I got an answer: The `java.awt.printerjob` system property was set to `sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob`.  Apparently this is a handy PrinterJob subclass if you like blocky pixelated output on your printer.  Instead, I get an instance of `sun.print.PSPrinterJob` if it's available, like so:

```
PrinterJob printerJob = null;
try {
    if (System.getProperty("java.awt.printerjob").equals("sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob")) {
        // WPrinterJob sends crappy GIF images to the printer, and everything looks all blocky
        // try to get an instance of a PSPrinterJob instead
        printerJob = (PrinterJob) Class.forName("sun.print.PSPrinterJob").newInstance();
    }
} catch (Throwable e1) {
    log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not instaniate sun.print.PSPrinterJob", e1);
}
if (printerJob == null) {
      printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
}
```

Comment: FYI, Java 8 on Mac seems to set this value to `sun.lwawt.macosx.CPrinterJob`